# One button two onclick events

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

Iam trying to trigger two functions from a single button. When i click the button it should go to a function check() and also its should open a popup window with a php script. How will i achieve it. I tried different methods but not able to achieve. Any one can help me?

```
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Save and Continue" onClick="OpenWindows(); return check();" />
```

The check() function is below:

```
 function check(){
     var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById("customer_idSet");
        filter = input.value;
        ul = document.getElementById("customer_list");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {   
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("sup")[0];
            if (filter==a.innerHTML) {
                return true;
            } 
        }
        alert("Please select the customer from dropdown or add a new customer");
        return false;
    }
```

From Openwindows() function how can i trigger a popup?

Comment: you can include OpenWindows() code in check function itself

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: How you injecting OpenWindows()? Is it injected correctly in your html page?

Comment: No i was not able to inject openWindows() properly in my page.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `check()`, and then call `OpenWindows()` from check;

```
function check(){
   ....
   OpenWindows();
}
```

Comment: From Openwindows() function how can i trigger a popup?

Answer (score 0):

I think your onClick() implementation was correct. But may be there is a problem injecting OpenWindows() method in your html page. I add an example of multiple function call in single click based on your implementation and its working.

**Example:**

```js
function check1(){
  console.log('check1');
}

function check2(){
  console.log('check2');
  window.open('//www.google.com', '_blank');
}
```

```html
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Save and Continue" onClick="check2(); check1();" />
```

See the plunker example:[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/m3XVczn7TXSY7SBTxzQI?p=preview)

Comment: Your script is working but can you help me with opening a pop up window from the function?

Comment: If you want to open a new window, just do: `window.open('http://your-domain.com', '_blank')`

Comment: @SidMenon please help me to understand what dows your pop up window do? is it a dialog box like alert, prompt, confirm or its a modal or its a completely new window?

Comment: I tried this way, but not working..onclick="return check(); window.open('http://your-domain.com', '_blank');

Comment: @SidMenon so far my understanding you want to open a new tab and also want function check. Am i correct?

Comment: Its a completely new window. Not basically a tab but a new pop up window or a modal is also fine.

Comment: Basically when user clicks button it has to save the data and open a new popup window with my php script.

Comment: If you want popup window you might need permission from browser. Example chrome by default deny popup window. So I suggest to crate modal for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of adding methods against a single DOM. One way has been already illustrated by you in the question.

Next is I am describing here. Instead of adding `onclick` in the HTML, one can do it in the scripting as below:

**HTML:**

```
input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="clickMe" value="Click" />
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#clickMe').on('click', OpenWindows);
});
```

where `OpenWindows` is the method in the JS, which contains the two other methods i.e. `check()` and `openPopup()`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/oubz8xjy/)